# is it possible run a devexpress blazor component on a mvc view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, devexpress, blazor

I have a cshtml view running on asp mvc .net core like this:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Components.PatientP>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

It links to a razor component containing a tag for devexpress blazor reporting

```
<DxDocumentViewer ReportUrl="PatientPending" Height="800px" Width="100%">
        <DxDocumentViewerTabPanelSettings Width="180" />
</DxDocumentViewer>
```

The page loads but the report is not being rendered, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: DevExpress has the most awesome [support](http://supportcenter.devexpress.com/) I ever came across. Why not ask them there on how to solve this?

Comment: no answers for two questions 4 days ago, yes, very awesome.

Comment: once you get a response, post it here